# Return string with dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I have a variable `@sqlFinal` which is of type `Varchar(500)`.

I fill the variable as the stored procedure runs. I want to dynamically return what is in the string to show the results

```
SELECT @sqlFinal = 'SELECT @Error_Return AS Final_Report'
--PRINT @sqlFinal
EXEC (@sqlFinal)
```

But I get the following error

> *Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@Error_Return".*

Comment: did you declare `@Error_Return`?

Comment: Sorry I have @Error_Return as a Varchar(500) already declared but did not state that.

Comment: Post all your code with your variables declared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that @Error_Return is in the same scope as @SqlFinal?

If you just need to return the contents of @Error_Return, you can just execute this line:

```
SELECT @Error_Return as Final_Report
```

... making it a static SQL line rather than a dynamic one.

But if that's not acceptable, you may have to use sp_executeSQL instead.  This allows you to pass variables to the line you're executing.

```
Declare @Error_Return VARCHAR(10)
Set @Error_return= 'Whatever'

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT @Error_Return as Final_Report', N'@Error_Return varchar(10)', @Error_Return
```

Answer (score 1):

The `EXEC()` function creates a *new* execution scope. Variables, like @Error_Return, that are defined in the the current scope will not be available in the Exec() function. Look into [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) instead.